# How can I tell if an Android device is locked to a specific carrier?

Tags: tablet, sim-card, sim-unlocking, cellular-radio

I want to know if an Android tablet is specific to a cellular carrier (T-Mobile, Verizon, etc.). The particular one I have in my hand now is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A, but I have multiple types of tablets in my environment, so I need to know a way to understand if the tablet is locked to T-Mobile or if I can simply swap SIMs to a different carrier.

Where can I look in my T-Mobile tablet to check?

Comment: I would start by reading out the correct model name from the Android settings phone/tablet info page, especially the `SM-*` name which you can use to check the hardware spec on various pages (including supported bands).

Comment: This is going to sound super simple, but I keep a AT&T SIM around just for this... Pop in a T-Mobile SIM and it works, then pop in the AT&T SIM, if it works it's unlocked, if it pops up a window looking for a code to carrier unlock the device, well, it's locked. Note that the SIM does NOT have to active, if the device is carrier locked it won't even attempt to connect to the network.